# Removing urlEncodingAttributes values breaks the page (hybris)

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlet-filters, urlencode, sap-commerce-cloud

I copied powertoolsinitialdata and made it my store after changing names.

Now i can go to localhost my site and see powertools products.

In `site.impex` , there is a part:

```
# CMS Site
INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];theme(code);channel(code);stores(uid);contentCatalogs(id);defaultCatalog(id);defaultLanguage(isoCode);urlPatterns;active;previewURL;startingPage(uid,$contentCV);urlEncodingAttributes;defaultPromotionGroup(Identifier)[default=mysitePromoGrp]
;$siteUid;lambda;B2B;$storeUid;$contentCatalog;$productCatalog;$defaultLanguage;(?s).*;true;$storefrontContextRoot/?site=$siteUid;homepage;storefront,language,currency;
```

This is default from powertools.

So  i have to go to

https://localhost:9002/mysite/en/USD/

instead of only localhost.

For it, i deleted the those parameters.

and made `site.impex` like this

```
# CMS Site
INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];theme(code);channel(code);stores(uid);contentCatalogs(id);defaultCatalog(id);defaultLanguage(isoCode);urlPatterns;active;previewURL;startingPage(uid,$contentCV);urlEncodingAttributes;defaultPromotionGroup(Identifier)[default=mysitePromoGrp]
;$siteUid;lambda;B2B;$storeUid;$contentCatalog;$productCatalog;$defaultLanguage;(?s).*;true;$storefrontContextRoot/?site=$siteUid;homepage;;;
```

I deleted only last 3 parameters

```
storefront,language,currency;
```

which are urlencodinggatrributes.

Then i again made ant initialize (also i tried importing from console).

After clearing cache or going inconite, i see such a bottom of powertools

https://pasteboard.co/HqKOciV.png

Why is that? Why bottom of websiter is not proper? I want to remove those parameters. Should i remove from also somewhere else?

I dont want to do via wcms or adding another impex like

```
 INSERT_UPDATE CMSSite;uid[unique=true];urlEncodingAttributes
```

I could not fin any solution for that wish.

This is error when i go to homepage. This is not shown after i import default impex:

> ```
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> ```
>
> Jun 22, 2018 3:52:57 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [DispatcherServlet] threw
>   exception
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: In
>   URL tags, when the "context" attribute
>   is specified, values of both "context"
>   and "url" must start with "/".
>           at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.UrlSupport.resolveUrl(UrlSupport.java:190)
>           at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.UrlSupport.doEndTag(UrlSupport.java:141)
>           at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.responsive.product.productPrimaryImage_tag._jspx_meth_c_005furl_005f0(productPrimaryImage_tag.java:306)
>           at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.responsive.product.productPrimaryImage_tag._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f0(productPrimaryImage_tag.java:270)
>           at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.responsive.product.productPrimaryImage_tag._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f0(productPrimaryImage_tag.java:236)
>           at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.responsive.product.productPrimaryImage_tag.doTag(productPrimaryImage_tag.java:158)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.cms.productcarouselcomponent_jsp._jspx_meth_product_005fproductPrimaryImage_005f0(productcarouselcomponent_jsp.java:664)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.cms.productcarouselcomponent_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f1(productcarouselcomponent_jsp.java:588)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.cms.productcarouselcomponent_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fotherwise_005f0(productcarouselcomponent_jsp.java:541)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.cms.productcarouselcomponent_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f1(productcarouselcomponent_jsp.java:301)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.cms.productcarouselcomponent_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fwhen_005f0(productcarouselcomponent_jsp.java:266)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.cms.productcarouselcomponent_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fchoose_005f0(productcarouselcomponent_jsp.java:225)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.cms.productcarouselcomponent_jsp._jspService(productcarouselcomponent_jsp.java:158)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at com.itelligence.mysite.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:90)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:590)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:524)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:160)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at com.itelligence.mysite.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:90)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:590)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:524)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:895)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:648)
>           at de.hybris.platform.acceleratorcms.component.renderer.impl.GenericViewCMSComponentRenderer.renderView(GenericViewCMSComponentRenderer.java:101)
>           at de.hybris.platform.acceleratorcms.component.renderer.impl.CachingCMSComponentRenderer.renderView(CachingCMSComponentRenderer.java:92)
>           at de.hybris.platform.acceleratorcms.component.renderer.impl.GenericViewCMSComponentRenderer.renderComponent(GenericViewCMSComponentRenderer.java:85)
>           at de.hybris.platform.acceleratorcms.component.renderer.impl.DefaultCMSComponentRendererRegistry.renderComponent(DefaultCMSComponentRendererRegistry.java:80)
>           at de.hybris.platform.acceleratorcms.component.slot.impl.DefaultCMSPageSlotComponentService.renderComponent(DefaultCMSPageSlotComponentService.java:334)
>           at de.hybris.platform.acceleratorcms.tags2.CMSComponentTag.renderItem(CMSComponentTag.java:298)
>           at de.hybris.platform.acceleratorcms.tags2.CMSComponentTag.doStartTag(CMSComponentTag.java:254)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.pages.layout.landingLayout2Page_jsp._jspx_meth_cms_005fcomponent_005f4(landingLayout2Page_jsp.java:553)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.pages.layout.landingLayout2Page_jsp._jspx_meth_cms_005fpageSlot_005f4(landingLayout2Page_jsp.java:516)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.pages.layout.landingLayout2Page_jsp.access$4(landingLayout2Page_jsp.java:492)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.pages.layout.landingLayout2Page_jsp$Helper.invoke0(landingLayout2Page_jsp.java:744)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.pages.layout.landingLayout2Page_jsp$Helper.invoke(landingLayout2Page_jsp.java:766)
>           at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.responsive.template.page_tag$Helper.invoke2(page_tag.java:477)
>           at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.responsive.template.page_tag$Helper.invoke(page_tag.java:509)
>           at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.responsive.template.master_tag.doTag(master_tag.java:260)
>           at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.responsive.template.page_tag._jspx_meth_template_005fmaster_005f0(page_tag.java:266)
>           at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.responsive.template.page_tag.doTag(page_tag.java:199)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.pages.layout.landingLayout2Page_jsp._jspx_meth_template_005fpage_005f0(landingLayout2Page_jsp.java:201)
>           at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.responsive.pages.layout.landingLayout2Page_jsp._jspService(landingLayout2Page_jsp.java:168)
>           at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:467)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:392)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:301)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$StatisticsGatewayFilter.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:390)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.itelligence.mysite.storefront.filters.CustomerLocationRestorationFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomerLocationRestorationFilter.java:52)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.itelligence.mysite.storefront.filters.CartRestorationFilter.doFilterInternal(CartRestorationFilter.java:64)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.itelligence.mysite.storefront.filters.AnonymousCheckoutFilter.doFilterInternal(AnonymousCheckoutFilter.java:36)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>           at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at de.hybris.platform.personalizationservices.filter.CxPersonalizationFilter.doFilterInternal(CxPersonalizationFilter.java:66)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.itelligence.mysite.storefront.filters.FileUploadFilter.doFilterInternal(FileUploadFilter.java:51)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.itelligence.mysite.storefront.filters.UrlEncoderFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlEncoderFilter.java:83)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.itelligence.mysite.storefront.filters.StorefrontFilter.doFilterInternal(StorefrontFilter.java:74)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.itelligence.mysite.storefront.filters.cms.CMSSiteFilter.doFilterInternal(CMSSiteFilter.java:100)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.itelligence.mysite.storefront.filters.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestLoggerFilter.java:71)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at com.itelligence.mysite.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:90)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.WebAppMediaFilter.doFilter(WebAppMediaFilter.java:140)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:99)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.Log4JFilter.doFilter(Log4JFilter.java:44)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.session.HybrisSpringSessionFilter.doFilter(HybrisSpringSessionFilter.java:69)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain$InternalFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:271)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.processStandardFilterChain(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:201)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.AbstractPlatformFilterChain.doFilterInternal(AbstractPlatformFilterChain.java:179)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at com.itelligence.mysite.storefront.filters.UrlPathFilter.doFilterInternal(UrlPathFilter.java:82)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at com.itelligence.mysite.storefront.filters.AcceleratorAddOnFilter.doFilter(AcceleratorAddOnFilter.java:90)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.processPatternsAndDoFilter(XSSFilter.java:358)
>           at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter.doFilter(XSSFilter.java:306)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>
> WARN  [hybrisHTTP27]
>   [DefaultCMSComponentRendererRegistry]
>   Error processing component tag.
>   currentComponent
>   [ProductCarouselComponentModel
>   (8796115141692@1)] exception: An
>   exception occurred processing JSP page
>   [/WEB-INF/views/responsive/cms/productcarouselcomponent.jsp]
>   at line [48]
>
> 45:
>   46:
>    47:
>    48:
>   49:
>   50:
>   ${fn:escapeXml(product.name)} 51:
>
> Stacktrace:

Also, i tried to change from backoffice. I removed all parameters but it is same. I got same error.

my `localproperties` is:

```
website.mystore.http=http://mystore.local:9001/
website.mystore.https=https://mystore.local:9002/

hac.webroot=/hac
mystorestorefront.webroot=
storefrontContextRoot=
```